# Ionic cordova build failed for android?

Tags: java, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I am working on ionic 3 project where I build apk for android couple of time everything worked fine but after I update some markup then I try to run 'ionic cordova build android' it's ended up with build 'Failed' error.
Then I removed the updated markup but nothing helped.

I followed the related solution on everywhere but still I am getting same build failed error.

## This is my ionic info:

```
 @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 8.0.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.8
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.11.0
npm               : 5.6.0
OS                : Windows 7
```

## ionic cordova plugin list

```
cordova-plugin-app-update 1.6.0 "AppUpdate"
cordova-plugin-appversion 1.0.0 "App Version"
cordova-plugin-camera 2.4.1 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.1 "Device" 
cordova-plugin-facebook4 4.2.1 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-file 5.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.0.5 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.1.16 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder 3.2.2 "NativeGeocoder"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
mx.ferreyra.callnumber 0.0.2 "Cordova Call Number Plugin"
```

## Error:

```
Parsing json 
file:D:\Ionic\folderName\HJAPP\projectName\platforms\android\google-services.json
:generateDebugResources
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

BUILD FAILED
```

How will I solve this error and build apk ?

Comment: remove platform then try

Comment: Thanks I did this multiple of time but not worked I had plugin problem and I found the solution @AnandhSp

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search I found solution here.
    https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-cordova-run-android-firebase-error-all-of-a-sudden/163204/22

## Solution

```
 step:1
 add @Override in MyFirebaseMessagingService in the path ionicProjectName\platforms\android\src\com\gae\scaffolder\plugin\MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    Log.d("NEW_TOKEN",s);
}
step2:
delete file MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java 
..In the same folder you will find MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java

step:3
re-open terminal and build again
this works for me.
```

For more details you can also read here